# c++ single linked list segmentation fault t

Tags: c++, singly-linked-list

I am trying to write a code making a single linked list. I want to put all my array elements into each node and link them. But when I run my code I keep getting the segmentation fault error. I do not get why I am getting this error.
Can anybody help?? Thanks!!

linked_list_main.cc

```html
#include <iostream>
#include "linked_list.h"

int main() {
    int array[5];
    List<int> list(array, 5);
    std::cout << list;
    return 0;

} 
  
template <class T>                                                                                    
class Node {                                                                                    
    public:                                                                           
          T data;                                                                                       
          Node<T>* next;                                                                                                                                                                                    
};
```

This is my linked_list.h file.

```html
                                                                                                                                                                       
class List {                                                                                          
    private:                                                                                          
        Node<T> *head;                                                                                
    public:                                                                                           
        List() : head(NULL) {};                                                                       
        ~List() {                                                                                     
            Node<T>* ptr;                                                                             
            for(ptr = head; ptr == NULL; ptr = head->next)                                            
                delete ptr;                                                                           
            }                                                                                             
        List(T* arr, int n_nodes){                                                                    
            Node<T>* tmp = head;                                                                      
                for(int i = 0; i < n_nodes; i++ ) {                                                       
                    Node<T>* node = new Node<T>;                                                          
                    node->data = arr[i];                                                                  
                        if(tmp != NULL) {                                                                     
                            node->next = tmp;                                                                 
                            tmp = node;                                                                       
                        }                                                                                     
                  }                                                                                         
        }                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                      
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, List<T>& rhs) {                              
            Node<T>* cur = rhs.head;                                                                                                                                                                     
            while(cur != NULL) {                                                                                                                                                                            
                if(cur->next == NULL)                                                                                                                                                                        
                    out << cur->data << " ";                                                                                                                                                                
                else                                                                                                                                                                                        
                    out << cur->data << ", ";                                                                                                                                                                 
                cur = cur->next;                                                                                                                                                                               
            }                                                                                         
        }                                                                                             
};
```

Comment: You might want to think a bit harder about what your destructor is doing.

Comment: I thought that would get to every Node<T> that I made and delete the dynamically allocated memories. Isn't it what it is doing?

Comment: "As long as `ptr` does *not* point to anything, delete the node that it points to and move on to the next node". Does it sound correct to you?

Comment: It is a nullptr at first but it moves on to the next which is head->next. I don't get it. It might seem silly that I do not get why these don't work but I am a beginner I hope people explain not just say develop yourself..:(

Comment: If `p` is a null pointer then A) `delete p` has no effect, and B) `p->next` is invalid.  (Bring out pencil and paper and draw your list and your variables with boxes and arrows. It's the best way to work out pointer code.)

Comment: Then `for(Node<T>*ptr = head->next; ptr==NULL; ptr->next)` is this right? If it starts with head->next, then it is no longer starting with null pointer.

Comment: You won't guess your way to the correct solution, but from your `<<`, it looks like you know how to loop over all nodes in the list. Are you having problems writing that loop in `for` form?

Comment: I think I have the concept but having trouble writing it into the codes..

Comment: The `<<` loop in for-form is `for (Node<T>* cur = rhs.head; cur != NULL; cur = cur->next) { if ... }`. (It's a very mechanical translation: `init; while (condition) {stuff; next;}` --> `for (init; condition; next) { stuff; }`)

Answer (score 2):

You need to change this

```
List(T* arr, int n_nodes){
    Node<T>* tmp = head;
    ...
}
```

to this

```
List(T* arr, int n_nodes){
    Node<T>* tmp = NULL;
    ...
    head = tmp;
}
```

Pointers are tricky, learn to use a debugger. Will be the best hour you've ever spent when learning how to program.

Comment: add `head=tmp;` to which part? Can you be more specific?

Comment: @DoyoungKim to the last line of the `List(T* arr, int n_nodes)` constructor. Think about it, every constructor must initialise `head` but in your code `List(T* arr, int n_nodes)` doesn't.

Comment: okay, I got the part with the constructor and operator return part! Thanks!

Comment: But with operator << part, it doesn't get into the while loop which has the condition of (cur != NULL). I don't get it.. why wouldn't it print out anything..?

Comment: Don't I call the constructor once?(when List<int> li(array, 5) is read)?

Comment: @john if I put `head = tmp;` at the end of my line of constructor, when I print out the elements, it goes backwards printing "13, 21, 9, 7, 12" because head points to the last element. But this is not what I want. I want to print "12, 7, 9, 21, 13"